# added external jar didn't work in google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jar

I'm using dom4j to parse a xml file in order to get some data that I want to use in my project. I tested my parser locally, it is working fine. Then I added dom4j jar as external jar from Properties of project. I went to Java Build Path Part add clicked on Add External Jars. It doesn't give any error and also I can deploy my project on Google App Engine. When I go to page and do some actions, it gives this error:

```
Uncaught exception from servlet
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/DocumentException
```

Could you please help me to solve it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add your jar in WEB-INF/lib
and deploy